# How to access JSON body in the response object when status of 400/403/500 are sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Whenever server returns 200 status, I'm able to get the JSON `msg` property as response.

But when status code 400/403/500 is sent, the error is sent in the browser console and I can see my "msg" inside the error object(in the console)

How to extract it with response inside Angular to show it to the user?

Consider the following code :

```
res.status(403).json // {msg : "Password Incorrect"}
```

How should I access the `msg` field?

Answer (score 0):

How would you catch both a 200 OR a 422 from a resource, both containing valid JSON in the body?

This is the only way I've figured it out so far.

```
fetch(`${endpoint}user/${record.id}/`, {
  method: 'put',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth}`
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(record)
})
.then((result) => result.json())
.then((result) => {

    if (result.id) {
      dispatch(savedUser( result ));
    } else {
      dispatch(savingUserError( result ));
    }

});
```

Comment: Was it use full ?